# Tensordot for numpy array and scipy sparse matrix

Tags: numpy, matrix, scipy, sparse-matrix

For a current project I have to compute the inner product of a lot of vectors with the same matrix (which is quite sparse). The vectors are associated with a two dimensional grid so I store the vectors in a three dimensional array:

E.g:

`X` is an array of dim `(I,J,N)`. The matrix `A` is of dim `(N,N)`. Now the task is to compute `A.dot(X[i,j])` for each `i,j` in `I,J`.

For numpy arrays, this is quite easily accomplished with

```
Y = X.dot(A.T)
```

Now I'd like to store `A` as sparse matrix since it is sparse and only contains a very limited number of nonzero entries which results in a lot of unnecessary multiplications. Unfortunately, the above solution won't work since the numpy dot doesn't work with sparse matrices. And to the best of my knowledge there is not tensordot-like operation for scipy sparse.

Does anybody know a nice and efficient way to compute the above array `Y` with a sparse matrix `A`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The obvious approach is to run a loop over your vectors and use the sparse matrix's `.dot` method:

```
def naive_sps_x_dense_vecs(sps_mat, dense_vecs):
    rows, cols = sps_mat.shape
    I, J, _ = dense_vecs.shape
    out = np.empty((I, J, rows))
    for i in xrange(I):
        for j in xrange(J):
            out[i, j] = sps_mat.dot(dense_vecs[i, j])
    return out
```

But you may be able to speed things up a little by reshaping your 3d array to 2d and avoid the Python looping:

```
def sps_x_dense_vecs(sps_mat, dense_vecs):
    rows, cols = sps_mat.shape
    vecs_shape = dense_vecs.shape
    dense_vecs = dense_vecs.reshape(-1, cols)
    out = sps_mat.dot(dense_vecs.T).T
    return out.reshape(vecs.shape[:-1] + (rows,))
```

The problem is that we need to have the sparse matrix be the first argument, so that we can call its `.dot` method, which means that the return is transposed, which in turns means that after transposing, the last reshape is going to trigger a copy of the whole array. So for fairly large values of `I` and `J`, combined with not-so-large values of `N`, the latter method will be several times faster than the former, but performance may even be reversed for other combinations of the parameters:

```
n, i, j = 100, 500, 500
a = sps.rand(n, n, density=1/n, format='csc')
vecs = np.random.rand(i, j, n)

>>> np.allclose(naive_sps_x_dense_vecs(a, vecs), sps_x_dense_vecs(a, vecs))
True

n, i, j = 100, 500, 500
%timeit naive_sps_x_dense_vecs(a, vecs)
1 loops, best of 3: 3.85 s per loop
%timeit sps_x_dense_vecs(a, vecs)
1 loops, best of 3: 576 ms per 

n, i, j = 1000, 200, 200
%timeit naive_sps_x_dense_vecs(a, vecs)
1 loops, best of 3: 791 ms per loop
%timeit sps_x_dense_vecs(a, vecs)
1 loops, best of 3: 1.3 s per loop
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `jax`to achieve what you are looking for. Let's suppose your sparse matrix is in `csr_array`format. You would first transform it into a `jax BCOO array`

```
from scipy import sparse
from jax.experimental import sparse as jaxsparse
import jax.numpy as jnp

def convert_to_BCOO(x):
    x = x.transpose()  #get the transpose
    x = x.tocoo()
    x = jaxsparse.BCOO((x.data, jnp.column_stack((x.row, x.col))),
                       shape=x.shape)
    x = L.sort_indices()
```

You could then use `jax.sparsify` to create a sparsified dot product as follows.

```
def dot(x, y):
    return jnp.dot(x, y)
sp_dot = jaxsparse.sparsify(dot)

A_transpose = convert_to_BCOO(A)
Y = sp_dot(X,A_transpose)
```

The function `sp_dot` now follows the exact same rules as `numpy.dot`.

Hope this helps!